# the connection between matrix and convex cone

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, convex-cone

I'm trying to understand the connection between convex cone and matarix. according to Boyd  as you can see in the pic: X is a p.s.d matrix but how this matrix represent a convex cone? and why the matrix is looking like this the the value 'y' appears twice? [what am I missing from here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em2il.png)

Another thins is what should I do when the matrix is 3x3 or 4x4? how do I need to build the matrix then?

thnx in advanced

Comment: $S^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, the description is giving a visualisation of $S^2$. Higher orders don't have a nice compact description like $S^2$.

Comment: The cone here is a set of infinitely many 2x2 matrices that are positive definite.

Comment: yes,I understood what you said but how i convert matrix to cone and cone to matrix? for example if n = 3, why the matrix look like:
first line: | x1  x2  x3 |
second line: | x2  x4  x5 |
third line: | x3  x5  x6 |
and what this matrix say about the cone?

Comment: In which text book is this? can anyone give that refernece?/

Comment: It is "convex optimization" by Boyd. you can find the pdf in google for free. my question it from chapter 2

Answer (score 3):

First, let’s look at the definition of a cone:

> A subset $C$ of a vector space $V$ is a cone iff for all $x\in{C}$ and scalars $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha\geqslant0$, the vector $\alpha{x}\in{C}$.

So we are interested in the set $\mathbb{S}^n$ of positive semidefinite $n\times{n}$ matrices. All we need to do is check the definition above—*i.e.* check that for any $M\in\mathbb{S}^n$ and $\alpha\geqslant0$, the matrix $\alpha{M}$ is positive semidefinite (this isn’t so hard).

In 3 or 4 dimensions, you won’t be able to visualize this cone—it’s not necessarily helpful to consider the visualization. The use is in the definition above.

Also, the value $y$ appears twice because Boyd is talking about symmetric matrices.